# c++ googlemock Process finished with exit code -1073741515 (0xC0000135)

Tags: c++, googletest

I want to use googletest on a c++ program, however I am getting an error, one for missing dlls. Here is my code:

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include <iostream>

TEST(anilib, comparison) {
    std::cout << "hello world";
}
```

I also have this in CmakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.25)
project(anitinder2)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

include(FetchContent)
FetchContent_Declare(
        googletest
        # Specify the commit you depend on and update it regularly.
        URL https://github.com/google/googletest/archive/5376968f6948923e2411081fd9372e71a59d8e77.zip
)
# For Windows: Prevent overriding the parent project's compiler/linker settings
set(gtest_force_shared_crt ON CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(googletest)

add_executable(anitinder2 tests/test.cpp)
target_link_libraries(anitinder2 gtest gtest_main)
target_link_libraries(anitinder2 gmock gmock_main)
```

I tried removing everything from the test, and it still failed. I also wanted to note that I had it working at one point in time, then after trying to install some libraries it broke and no longer works, even going back to a working commit.

Comment: Obviously the first thing to do is find out which DLL is missing. Use a dependency walker to do that. There are several to choose from.